# Sistema de login

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Eu fiz um site no qual eu tenho implementado este ficheiro que pertence ao login mas nao me funciona

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function loginsuccessufully(){
    setTimeout("window.location='backoffice/view.php'", 3000);
}

function loginfalhou(){
    setTimeout("window.location='../historia.php'", 3000);
}
</script>

<? php  include('backoffice/db-config.php') ?>
<? php

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$db = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE nome = '$nome' and password = '$password' ") or die(mysql_error());
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($row);

if($num_row < 1){
    session_start();
    $_Session['nome']=$_POST['nome'];
    $_Session['password']=$_POST['password'];
    echo"tas dentro";
    echo" <script>loginsuccessufully()</script>";

} else{
    echo"Login falhoe";
    echo" <script> loginfalhou() </script>";

}
?>
```

nao me da erros simplesmente executa o ultimo echo

Comment: Para começar, mysql_* não funciona nas versões mais recentes do PHP, você pode usar Mysqli ou PDO

Comment: @braulio_holtz Você sabe qual versão de PHP ele usa? Você sabe se o erro está no driver do banco?

Comment: nao nao sei onde ta  erro, ele nao me executa o codigo

Comment: O último `echo`... hmm... você se refere à "*Login falhoe*"?

Comment: o que me aparece no browser é isto

loginsuccessufully()</script>";

} else{
    echo"Login falhoe";
    echo" <script> loginfalhou() </script>";

}
?>

Comment: @coiso Cria um arquivo php com o código <?php phpinfo(); e execute e mande o resultado, php version, algo assim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não use aspas simples em nomes de tabelas, apenas em valores.

```
$db = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE nome = '$nome' and password = '$password' ") or die(mysql_error());
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($row);
```

Passe a variavel `$db` para [mysql_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) no lugar de `$row`

```
$db = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE nome = '$nome' and password = '$password' ") or die(mysql_error());
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($db);
```

Answer (score 5):

#### 1. Alterar o adaptador do banco de dados (recomendado)

Você deveria usar **[PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** ou **[MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** ao invés de **mysql**.

#### 2. Tratamento do conteúdo provido pelo $_POST (recomendado)

**Nunca** passe variáveis mágicas de requisição (*$_POST*, *$_GET*, etc) sem uma [higienização](http://www.dicio.com.br/higienizacao/) adequada. Você está fazendo isso:

```
[...]

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

[...]
```

Quando falo de higienização, me refiro ao seu literal significado:

> s.f. Ação ou efeito de higienizar.
>
> *(Etm. higienizar + ção)*

E higienizar, por sua vez:

> v.t.d. Fazer com que fique limpo; ficar asseado: higienizar os
>   sanitários. Deixar de estar doente; ficar saudável ou higiênico.
>
> *(Etm. higiene + izar)*

As suas variáveis mágicas de requisição **não** estão saudáveis porque podem armazenar diversas malícias que podem prejudicar o seu aplicativo num todo; partimos desde injeção SQL até caracteres maliciosos que a sua aplicação não está preparada para lidar, podendo ser espaços ou até alguns mais *exóticos*.

#### 3. Problema na query

O seguinte fragmento de código não está correto:

```
[...]

$db = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE nome = '$nome' and password = '$password' ") or die(mysql_error());

[...]
```

O uso de aspas simples em variáveis de banco é **incorreto**. Ao invés disso, você pode usar os *totalmente opcionais* "`", ficando dessa forma:

```
[...]

$db = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE nome = '$nome' and password = '$password' ") or die(mysql_error());

[...]
```

#### 4. Problema na condição de registro de sessão

Você tem o seguinte fragmento:

```
[...]

if($num_row < 1){

[...]
```

O problema aí está na sua condição. Quer dizer então que se os resultados da sua consulta no banco forem menor que um, ou seja, retornar "0" login válido, você vai registrar uma sessão?

Substituimos, então, pelo seguinte:

```
[...]

if($num_row == 1) {

[...]
```

**Por que `== 1`?**

Se a quantidade de linhas retornadas for maior que um, significa que **temos mais de um resultado** – o que não pode ser verdade, porque aí ou temos um problema de query ou dois registros iguais (ou quase) no banco de dados.

Se a quantidade de linhas for **igual** a um, a margem de erro é *quase* zero. Portanto, fique com essa opção que é a mais adequada para o seu caso.

Answer (score 3):

**Erros Encontrados:**

```
$db = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE nome = '$nome' and password = '$password' ") or die(mysql_error());
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($row);
```

Você colocou `$db` na `mysql_query` e no `mysql_num_rows($row)`, seria então, `mysql_num_rows($db)`.

**Código melhorado:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loginsuccessufully(){
        setTimeout("window.location='backoffice/view.php'", 3000);
    }
    function loginfalhou(){
        setTimeout("window.location='../historia.php'", 3000);
    }
</script>

<?php 
    include('backoffice/db-config.php') 
    $nome      = $_POST['nome'];
    $password  = $_POST['password'];
    $query     = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE nome = '{$nome}' and password = '{$password}' limit 1") or die(mysql_error());    

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1){
        session_start();
        $_Session['nome']=$_POST['nome'];
        $_Session['password']=$_POST['password'];
        echo "tas dentro";
        echo" <script>loginsuccessufully()</script>";
    } else{
        echo"Login falhoe";
        echo" <script> loginfalhou() </script>";
    }
?>
```

Obs: Não é o código ideal para a solução, porque, contem [mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php)_* que é depreciado( utilize [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) ou [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)), a utilização de $_POST que deveria ser utilizado [filter_input](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

Comment: esse codigo ajudou mas agora aparece me este erro

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp\www\pap_site\backoffice\loginmanage.php on line 12

Comment: E qual seria o código da linha 12?

Comment: Qual a linha 12? eu fiz outra edição ...

Comment: ja me aparece outro erro, agora o erro é este Warning: include(backoffice/db-config.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\pap_site\backoffice\loginmanage.php on line 11


e a linha 11 é esta     include('backoffice/db-config.php') ;

Comment: @coiso, ele não ta achando o db-config.php na pasta backoffice !!!

Comment: Esse erro indica que o arquivo backoffice/db-config.php não existe, cheque sua existência acessando isso: localhost/backoffice/db-config.php.

Comment: @perdeu mas ele adicionou, tanto que ao perguntado o código da linha 11 ele respondeu: include('backoffice/db-config.php');